# Understanding the impact of "makePSOCKcluster"

Tags: r, function, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I am using the R programming language. Recently, I came across the following function in R `makePSOCKcluster`, which can be used to "accelerate" the speed at which R can perform certain tasks (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/future/versions/1.19.1/topics/makeClusterPSOCK).

Based on some posts that I have seen, it seems like the `makePSOCKcluster` acts like a "wrapper" in which you place your code that would like to "accelerate" , for example:

```
library(doParallel)
library(future)

cl <- makePSOCKcluster(6) # 6 cpu cores out of 8

registerDoParallel(cl)

### enter your code here

stopCluster(cl) # when finished`
```

I tried to adapt this setup to help accelerate an R procedure I am using:

```
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(6) # 6 cpu cores out of 8

registerDoParallel(cl)

### START

library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

results_table <- data.frame()

grid_function <- function(train_data, random_1, random_2, random_3, random_4, split_1, split_2, split_3) {
    
    
    
    #bin data according to random criteria
    train_data <- train_data %>% mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= random_1 & b1 <= random_3, "a", ifelse(a1 <= random_2 & b1 <= random_4, "b", "c")))
    
    train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
    
    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    
    #calculate random quantile ("quant") for each bin
    
    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_1)))
    
    table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_2)))
    
    table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_3)))
    
    
    
    
    #create a new variable ("diff") that measures if the quantile is bigger tha the value of "c1"
    table_a$diff = ifelse(table_a$quant > table_a$c1,1,0)
    table_b$diff = ifelse(table_b$quant > table_b$c1,1,0)
    table_c$diff = ifelse(table_c$quant > table_c$c1,1,0)
    
    #group all tables
    
    final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
    
    #create a table: for each bin, calculate the average of "diff"
    final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table %>%
                                   group_by(cat) %>%
                                   summarize(
                                       mean = mean(diff)
                                   ))
    
    #add "total mean" to this table
    final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table_2 %>% add_row(cat = "total", mean = mean(final_table$diff)))
    
    #format this table: add the random criteria to this table for reference
    final_table_2$random_1 = random_1
    
    final_table_2$random_2 = random_2
    
    final_table_2$random_3 = random_3
    
    final_table_2$random_4 = random_4
    
    final_table_2$split_1 = split_1
    
    final_table_2$split_2 = split_2
    
    final_table_2$split_3 = split_3
    
    
    
    
    results_table <- rbind(results_table, final_table_2)
    
    final_results = dcast(setDT(results_table), random_1 + random_2 + random_3 + random_4 + split_1 + split_2 + split_3 ~ cat, value.var = 'mean')
    
}

# create some data for this example
a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
b1 = rnorm(1000,100,5)
c1 = sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)
train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)




#grid
random_1 <- seq(80,100,5)
random_2 <- seq(85,120,5)
random_3 <- seq(85,120,5)
random_4 <- seq(90,120,5)
split_1 =  seq(0,1,0.1)
split_2 =  seq(0,1,0.1)
split_3 =  seq(0,1,0.1)
DF_1 <- expand.grid(random_1 , random_2, random_3, random_4, split_1, split_2, split_3)

#reduce the size of the grid for this example
DF_1 = DF_1[1:100000,]

colnames(DF_1) <- c("random_1" , "random_2", "random_3",                     "random_4", "split_1", "split_2", "split_3")

train_data_new <- copy(train_data)


resultdf1 <- apply(DF_1,1, # 1 means rows
                   FUN=function(x){
                       do.call(
                           # Call Function grid_function2 with the arguments in
                           # a list
                           grid_function,
                           # force list type for the arguments
                           c(list(train_data_new), as.list(
                               # make the row to a named vector
                               unlist(x)
                           )
                           ))
                   }
)

l = resultdf1
final_output = rbindlist(l, fill = TRUE)

### END

# when finished`
stopCluster(cl)
```

If I were to run the above code "locally", it would take a very long time to run. I ran the above code using the "makePSOCKcluster" wrapper - the code is still running.

**Question:** I am not sure if the "makePSOCKcluster" will actually make a difference - I am also not sure if I have used the "makePSOCKcluster" wrapper in the correct way. Can someone please tell me if what I am doing is correct? Are there any other ways to accelerate this code?

Comment: 1) `apply` always runs sequencially; 2) the function it's calling could be made to run faster.

Comment: @ Rui Barradas : thank you so much for your reply! if you have time, can you please show me how to do this? thanks!

Comment: FYI, the **future** package is not used in the above example, so `library(future)` can be dropped.  Instead, `makePSOCKcluster()` is part of the **parallel** package, so you need to attach that, i.e. `library(parallel)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt at it.

### 1. Rewrite the function

The function below is faster. I believe it could be made faster if data.frames were replaced by matrices. The results are not `identical` to the results output by the original function in the question because there are some `NA`'s that are now zeros.

```
library(foreach)
library(parallel)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

### START
grid_function_2 <- function(train_data, X) {
  random_1234 <- X[1:4]
  split_123 <- X[ seq_along(X)[-(1:4)] ]
  #bin data according to random criteria
  ia <- which(train_data$a1 <= random_1234[1] & train_data$b1 <= random_1234[3])
  ib <- which(train_data$a1 <= random_1234[2] & train_data$b1 <= random_1234[4])
  train_data$cat <- "c"
  train_data$cat[ia] <- "a"
  train_data$cat[ib] <- "b"
  train_data$cat <- factor(train_data$cat)
  #new splits
  table_abc <- split(train_data, train_data$cat)

  #calculate random quantile ("quant") for each bin

  table_abc <- lapply(seq_along(table_abc), function(i){
    quant <- quantile(table_abc[[i]]$c1, prob = split_123[i])
    diff <- as.integer(quant > table_abc[[i]]$c1)
    cbind(table_abc[[i]], diff = diff)
  })

  #group all tables
  final_table <- do.call(rbind, table_abc)
  final_table_2 <- final_table %>%
    group_by(cat) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(diff))

  #add "total mean" to this table
  final_table_2 <- final_table_2 %>% add_row(cat = "total", mean = mean(final_table$diff))

  #format this table: add the random criteria to this table for reference
  final_table_2$random_1 <- random_1234[1]
  final_table_2$random_2 <- random_1234[2]
  final_table_2$random_3 <- random_1234[3]
  final_table_2$random_4 <- random_1234[4]
  final_table_2$split_1 <- split_123[1]
  final_table_2$split_2 <- split_123[2]
  final_table_2$split_3 <- split_123[3]

  dcast(as.data.table(final_table_2), random_1 + random_2 + random_3 + random_4 + split_1 + split_2 + split_3 ~ cat, value.var = 'mean')
}
```

---

### 2. The test data

The test data sets are smaller and made reproducible by setting the RNG seed.

```
# make the results reproducible
set.seed(2021)

# create some data for this example
a1 <- rnorm(1000,100,10)
b1 <- rnorm(1000,100,5)
c1 <- sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)
train_data <- data.frame(a1,b1,c1)

#grid
n <- 3
random_1 <- seq(80,100,5)[1:n]
random_2 <- seq(85,120,5)[1:n]
random_3 <- seq(85,120,5)[1:n]
random_4 <- seq(90,120,5)[1:n]
split_1 <- seq(0,1,0.1)[1:n]
split_2 <- seq(0,1,0.1)[1:n]
split_3 <- seq(0,1,0.1)[1:n]
DF_1 <- expand.grid(random_1 , random_2, random_3, random_4, split_1, split_2, split_3)

# smaller data set with 3^7 rows
dim(DF_1)
#[1] 2187    7

## NOT RUN
#reduce the size of the grid for this example
#DF_1 <- DF_1[1:100000,]

colnames(DF_1) <- c("random_1" , "random_2", "random_3", "random_4",
                    "split_1", "split_2", "split_3")

train_data_new <- copy(train_data)
```

---

### 3. Timings

And now the comparative tests.
The reference value is `t0 <- system.time({original apply loop and function})`.

Then there are three tests, with `apply/new function`, with `mclapply` **(not on Windows)** and with `parLapply`.

```
t1 <- system.time({
  resultdf1 <- apply(DF_1, 1, # 1 means rows
                     FUN = function(x){
                       grid_function_2(train_data_new, x)
                     }
  )
})
final_output2 <- rbindlist(resultdf1, fill = TRUE)

# This cannot be run on Windows    
t2 <- system.time({
  ncores <- detectCores()
  resultdf1 <- mclapply(1:nrow(DF_1), function(i){
    grid_function_2(train_data_new, DF_1[i, ])
  },
  mc.cores = ncores - 1L)
})
final_output3 <- rbindlist(resultdf1, fill = TRUE)

t3 <- system.time({
  ncores <- detectCores()
  cl <- makePSOCKcluster(ncores - 1L) # reserve 1 cpu core
  clusterExport(cl, "train_data_new")
  clusterExport(cl, "DF_1")
  clusterExport(cl, "grid_function_2")
  clusterEvalQ(cl, "train_data_new")
  clusterEvalQ(cl, "DF_1")
  clusterEvalQ(cl, "grid_function_2")
  clusterEvalQ(cl, library(dplyr))
  clusterEvalQ(cl, library(data.table))
  resultdf1 <- parLapply(
    cl = cl,
    X = 1:nrow(DF_1),
    function(i){
      grid_function_2(train_data_new, DF_1[i, ])
    }
  )
  # when finished`
  stopCluster(cl)
})
final_output4 <- rbindlist(resultdf1, fill = TRUE)
```

---

### 4. Check the results

Like I said above, there are `NA` values mismatches when comparing the original `final_output` with this `final_output2`.

```
all.equal(final_output, final_output2)
#[1] "Column 'b': 'is.NA' value mismatch: 0 in current 243 in target"

identical(final_output2, final_output3)
#[1] TRUE
identical(final_output2, final_output4)
#[1] TRUE
```

As for the timings, remove `t2` if the code is to be run on Windows. The fastest are `t2` and `t3` by around an order of magnitude.

```
rbind(t0, t1, t2, t3)
```

Comment: @ Rui Barradas: thank you for your wonderful answer! I will have to spend some time to try and understand your answer - a lot of this is far beyond my knowledge.

Comment: What did you mean when you wrote "# This cannot be run on Windows "? Is there a reason why this cannot be run on windows?

Comment: What is the difference between final_output2, final_output3, final_output4, final_output5?

Comment: @stats555 1) Windows only allows sockets, not forking. 2) In my code there was a serious bug, I had `mclapply` and `parLapply` results assigned to `final_output*`, when it should be `resultdf1`. `final_output*` are created only with `rbindlist`. There is no difference between `final_output2`, `final_output3` and `final_output4`, this is tested at the end.

Comment: @ Rui Barradas: I am revisiting your answer (in the past year and a half, I have continued to self-learn and I think I have learned more compared to when I originally posted this question). Is there a reason that "t2" that does not work in Windows? Is this because of the mclapply(0 function? thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob *"Is this because of the mclapply() function?"* Yes, it is. `mcapply` creates socket clusters by forking.

Comment: @ Rui Barradas: Thank you so much for your answer! I am working on this question here and wondering if psockcluster might be applicable for this question - can you please take a look at it if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75851789/r-creating-a-matrix-to-store-join-results thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob Sorry but I cannot be of help, I don't know much about spatial stats. But if you ave a double loop and want to give parallelism a try, before the outer loop create a list instead of a matrix and replace the *inner* loop by `parSapply`.

Comment: @stats_noob Something like `coverage_matrix <- vector("list", n_file_1)` then fill the list with the results of `parSapply`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! I will work on this!

Comment: @ Rui Barradas: I attempted to implement the approach you provided in this question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75909761/transforming-a-loop-into-a-function-for-parallel-computing .... it runs, but I am not sure if its correct. can you please take a look at it if you have time? thank you so much!