# R: Creating a Matrix to Store Join Results

Tags: r, r-sf

I have these two shapefiles in R:

- file_1:https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/alternative_alternatif.cfm?l=eng&dispext=zip&teng=lada000b21a_e.zip&k=%20%20%20151162&loc=//www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2021/geo/sip-pis/boundary-limites/files-fichiers/lada000b21a_e.zip
- file_2: https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/alternative_alternatif.cfm?l=eng&dispext=zip&teng=lpc_000b21a_e.zip&k=%20%20%20%20%207778&loc=//www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2021/geo/sip-pis/boundary-limites/files-fichiers/lpc_000b21a_e.zip

I imported these files into R:

```
file_1 <- sf::st_read("C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/folder1/lada000b21a_e.shp", options = "ENCODING=WINDOWS-1252")
file_2 <- sf::st_read("C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/folder2/lpc_000b21a_e.shp", options = "ENCODING=WINDOWS-1252")

file_1 <- st_transform(file_1, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
file_2 <- st_transform(file_2, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")


> file_1

Simple feature collection with 1507 features and 4 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -95.15386 ymin: 41.68132 xmax: -74.34347 ymax: 56.05945
CRS:           +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84
First 10 features:
       ADAUID             DGUID LANDAREA PRUID                       geometry
1567 35010001 2021S051635010001 643.4007    35 MULTIPOLYGON (((-74.48809 4...
1568 35010002 2021S051635010002 605.0164    35 MULTIPOLYGON (((-74.55843 4...
1569 35010003 2021S051635010003 515.4641    35 MULTIPOLYGON (((-74.90049 4...

>file_2
> pop_mini
Simple feature collection with 310 features and 9 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -116.9893 ymin: 41.98072 xmax: -64.09933 ymax: 53.53916
CRS:           +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84
First 10 features:
   PCUID PCPUID         DGUID DGUIDP                 PCNAME PCTYPE PCCLASS LANDAREA PRUID                       geometry
1   0001 350001 2021S05100001   <NA>                  Acton      2       2   7.8376    35 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.00597 4...
5   0006 350006 2021S05100006   <NA>             Alexandria      4       2   2.0689    35 MULTIPOLYGON (((-74.63831 4...
6   0007 350007 2021S05100007   <NA>                 Alfred      4       2   0.8654    35 MULTIPOLYGON (((-74.87997 4...
```

**My Question:** I am trying to construct a matrix which shows what percent of each polygon in file_1 is covered by polygons in file_2 - and what percent of each polygon in file_2 is covered by polygons in file_1.

Based on some research I did (e.g. [R: Calculating Polygon Overlaps and Intersections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75849216/r-checking-matrix-sums) , https://github.com/r-lib/isoband/issues/6 ), I first repaired the geometries with both of these files:

```
library(lwgeom)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# Repair invalid geometries in file_1
file_1$geometry <- st_make_valid(file_1$geometry)

# Repair invalid geometries in file_2
file_2$geometry <- st_make_valid(file_2$geometry)
```

Then, I tried to write a matrix-loop procedure to calculate the percent coverage of pairwise polygons in both files:

```
# Calculate the number of polygons in each file
n_file_1 <- nrow(file_1)
n_file_2 <- nrow(file_2)
# Use st_intersection to find overlapping polygons
intersections <- st_intersection(file_1, file_2)

# Create a matrix to store coverage percentages
coverage_matrix <- matrix(0, n_file_1, n_file_2)

# Calculate the number of polygons in each file
n_ada <- nrow(file_1)
n_pop <- nrow(file_2)

# Create a matrix to store coverage percentages
coverage_matrix <- matrix(0, n_file_1, n_file_2)

# Calculate coverage percentages for each pair of polygons
for (i in seq_len(n_file_1)) {
    for (j in seq_len(n_file_2)) {
        intersection_area <- st_area(st_intersection(file_1[i,], file_2[j,]))
        if (length(intersection_area) > 0) {
            file_1_area <- st_area(file_1[i,])
            coverage_matrix[i,j] <- 100 * intersection_area / file_1_area
        }
        # Print intermediate results
        cat(paste0("i: ", i, ", j: ", j, ", coverage: ", coverage_matrix[i,j], "\n"))
    }
}

# Set row and column names for the coverage matrix
rownames(coverage_matrix) <- paste0("file_1 ", seq_len(n_file_1))
colnames(coverage_matrix) <- paste0("file_2 ", seq_len(n_file_2))

# Print the coverage matrix
print(coverage_matrix)
```

The code appears to be running :

```
i: 1, j: 1, coverage: 0
i: 1, j: 2, coverage: 0.349480438105992
i: 1, j: 3, coverage: 0
i: 1, j: 4, coverage: 0
```

**But I am not sure if I am doing this correctly.**

Can someone please show me how to do this? Is there a more efficient/faster way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I was linked here from your other question. Happy to look at this if I get the chance but what's the actual question? Is it about the correct way to measure the overlap between two polygons? Or is it how to efficiently create a pairwise matrix of overlaps? You seem to have done both - what's wrong with your method?

Comment: @ SamR: thank you for your reply! As I am new to geospatial analysis, I wanted to make sure I am doing this correctly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to figure out how to do this.

```
# Repair invalid geometries in file_1
file_1$geometry <- st_make_valid(file_1$geometry)

# Repair invalid geometries in file_2
file_2$geometry <- st_make_valid(file_2$geometry)


# Reproject if necessary
file_1 <- st_transform(file_1, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
file_2 <- st_transform(file_2, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

# Use st_intersection to find overlapping polygons
intersections <- st_intersection(file_1, file_2)

# Check for invalid features
invalid_features <- st_is_valid(intersections)

# Remove invalid features
intersections <- intersections[invalid_features, ]


# Calculate area of overlapping polygons
area_intersections <- st_area(intersections)

# Calculate area of all polygons in file_1 and file_2
area_file_1 <- st_area(file_1)
area_file_2 <- st_area(file_2)

# Calculate percentage coverage for each pair of polygons
coverage_matrix <- matrix(0, nrow(file_1), nrow(file_2))
for (i in seq_len(nrow(file_1))) {
    for (j in seq_len(nrow(file_2))) {
        # Calculate area of intersection between polygons i and j
        intersection_area <- sum(area_intersections[which(intersections$ADAUID == file_1$ADAUID[i] & 
                                                              intersections$PCUID == file_2$PCUID[j])])
        # Calculate percentage coverage
        coverage_matrix[i, j] <- intersection_area / (area_file_1[i] + area_file_2[j] - intersection_area)


    }
}

# View coverage matrix
coverage_matrix

# Set row and column names for the coverage matrix
rownames(coverage_matrix) <- file_1$ADAUID
colnames(coverage_matrix) <- file_2$PCUID
```

From here, I then process the result (there are multiple rows for each ADAUID so I need to group sum them):

```
# Convert matrix to data frame
coverage_df <- as.data.frame.table(coverage_matrix)

# Rename columns
names(coverage_df) <- c("adauid", "pcuid", "coverage_value")

# Filter non-zero coverage values
coverage_df <- coverage_df[coverage_df$coverage_value != 0, c("adauid", "coverage_value")]

coverage_df$coverage_value = coverage_df$coverage_value * 100
```

**This code seems to run faster - but is it correct?**

**Note:** Print Option

```
# Calculate percentage coverage for each pair of polygons
coverage_matrix <- matrix(0, nrow(file_1), nrow(file_2))
for (i in seq_len(nrow(file_1))) {
    for (j in seq_len(nrow(file_2))) {
        # Calculate area of intersection between polygons i and j
        intersection_area <- sum(area_intersections[which(intersections$ADAUID == file_1$ADAUID[i] & 
                                                              intersections$PCUID == file_2$PCUID[j])])
        # Calculate percentage coverage
        coverage_matrix[i, j] <- intersection_area / (area_file_1[i] + area_file_2[j] - intersection_area)
        # Print the percentage coverage
        print(paste0("Coverage for polygons ", i, " and ", j, ": ", coverage_matrix[i, j]))
    }
}
```